# Parent-Child Filter with QueryBuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filtering, parent-child, objectquery

Suppose I have 3 table: Table Employee, EmploymentHistory, and Languages. One employee can have many language and employment history.

Employee

```
ID  Name    Email
1   AAA aaa@gmail.com
2   BBB bbb@gmail.com
3   CCC ccc@gmail.com
```

Employment History

```
ID  EmployeeID   Company         Position
1   1            Devon Energy    aaa
2   2            Emric           bbb
3   3            Capcom          ccc
```

Language

```
ID  EmployeeID  Language    Level
1   1           English     Expert
2   2           Dutch       Expert
3   3           Franch      Expert
```

How to apply filter using ObjectQuery QueryBuilder ? Example: I want to filter employee with devon company. It should be employee "AAA".

```
var emp = Translate(context.Employees.Include("EmploymentHistories"));

public ObjectQuery<T> Translate<T>(ObjectQuery<T> objectQuery)
{
      objectQuery.Where("it.EmploymentHistories.Company = 'Devon Energy'"); // EmploymentHistories.Company is not found. How can I filter through it included property
}
```

Note: I'm using QueryBuilder for advanced filtering.

Best regards,

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 Day of excruciating pain, Finally I've found the solution. I used dynamic linq provided by microsoft [Dynamic LINQ](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/dynamiclinqcsharp.zip) to solve this problem